# ASP.Net Core javascript variables not accessible in console

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I'm attempting to add d3.js charts to my web app. Using the new JSON serializer I'm returning the results of the query to the View:

```
public IActionResult QuotationTracker()
{
    var query =
    (from p in _context.vQuotationTracker
    orderby p.quote
    select p)
    .ToList();

    ViewBag.data = query;

    return View(query);
}
```

This string is stored in Viewbag.data and passed into a javascript var json1:

```
<script>
    var json1 = @Json.Serialize(Viewbag.data);
</script>
```

Looking at this in DevTools I can see this has worked:

```
var json1 = [{"Apple","Orange","Pear"},{"Sample1","Sample2","Sample3"}]
```

But if I try to `console.log(json1)`, I'm told json1 is undefined. The script tag is located just before the  tag. Encasing the helper expression in single quotes does not help either:

```
var json1 = '@Json.Serialize(Viewbag.data)';
```

I've also been told that Viewbag and Viewdata shouldn't be used to pass data from the Model to the View. Why is that?

Comment: Have you tried `window.json1 = ...`? It should be the same, though.

Comment: You didn't notice the syntax error in your console?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
var json1 = [{"Apple","Orange","Pear"},["Sample1","Sample2","Sample3"]]
```

is not valid: There is a syntax error. (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ',').

I guess you want something like this instead

```
var json1 = [["Apple","Orange","Pear"],["Sample1","Sample2","Sample3"]].
```

You have probably a problem with the line

```
 @Json.Serialize(Viewbag.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Looking at this in DevTools I can see this has worked:
>
> var json1 = [{"Apple","Orange","Pear"},{"Sample1","Sample2","Sample3"}]

Your json is strange and it should be like

`[{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},{"key1":"value3","key2":"value4"}]`.

I test your code and it works well in my razor view:

```
@section Scripts {
<script>
   
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var json1 = @Json.Serialize(ViewBag.data);
        console.log(json1);
    });        
    
</script>

}
```

[image]